# Unable To Highlight All Text In Lucecne Search Highlighting in JAVA

Tags: java, jsp

```
String SearchText = request.getParameter(
                            "txtsearch").toString();
                    TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term("f",
                            SearchText));
                    QueryScorer scorer = new QueryScorer(query);
                    SimpleHTMLFormatter formatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter(
                            "<span class=\"highlight\">", "</span>");
                    org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter highlighter = new org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter(
                            formatter, scorer);

                    Fragmenter fragmenter = new SimpleFragmenter(
                            result.length());

                    highlighter.setTextFragmenter(fragmenter);
                    TokenStream tokenStream = new SnowballAnalyzer(
                            "English").tokenStream("f",
                            new StringReader(result));

                    String result1 = highlighter.getBestFragments(
                            tokenStream, result, 5, "...");

                    if (result1.length() == 0) {
                        result1 = result;
                    }
                    finalhtml = "<html>" + "<style>\n"
                            + ".highlight{\n"
                            + " background: yellow;\n" + "}\n"
                            + "</style>" + "<body>" + result1
                            + "</body></html>";
```

This is My Lucene Highlighting Code . result is My Html and Searchtext is my Text search which is Dynamic please check My code where am doing wrong some selected word is aHeighlighting like tax,delhi,Kolkatta  Etc I dont know where am doing wrong Please help me